# Meaning of the $I/mI$ in a given ring A

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I wish to understand the meaning behind the following phrase:

"Let A be a ring and let $m$ be the maximal ideal. 
Let $I$ be a principal ideal. Then $I/mI$ is a one dimensional $A/m$-vector space"

So what exactly is $I/mI$ ? And how do we view it as an $A/m$ vector space. (although $A/m$ is a field).

Cheers

Comment: What are your thoughts? This problem is very natural, everything is exactly what you would think it is.

Comment: First, there are, in general, multiple maximal ideals, so shouldn't it be "and let $m$ be **a** maximal ideal."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Unless the OP has left some information unspoken.

Comment: This is not 100% true. When $mI=I$ you get $I/mI$ is a $0$-dimensional vector space over $A/m.$ For example, if $A=k\times k$ with $k$ a field, and $m=I=\langle(1,0)\rangle$ then $mI=I.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any $A$ module annihilated by $m$ is [naturally an $A/m$ module](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1224888/29335).

Such is the case for $I/mI$.  And yes, $A/m$ is a field, so $I/mI$ is a vector space over $A/m$.

I'll leave it to you to show that if $I$ is principal, this is at most a $1$-dimensional $A/m$ space, since you said your main question was about what the previous stuff meant.

(Hint if you were supposed to assume $A$ is local (since you said "the maximal ideal"): $Im\neq I$ by Nakayama's Lemma.