# Need help showing that the only submodules of $M$ are the ones in an ascending chain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noetherian, principal-ideal-domains

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{Assumed facts:}$

$\textbf{Theorem 1:}$  Let $R$ be a ring.  Then the following conditions are equivalent:

$(1)$  Every ideal of $R$ is finitely generated

$(2)$  Every ascending sequences $I_1\subset I_2\subset I_3\subset\cdots$ of $R$ becomes stationary

$(3)$ Every set $M$ of ideals contiains a maximal element, i.e., an element $J\in M$ which is not properly contained in any $I\in M$

$\textbf{Definition:}$  A ring satisfying the equivalent conditions of theroem 1 is called a $\textbf{Noetherian ring.}$

$\textbf{Theorem 2:}$  Every principal ideal ring is Noetherian.

$\textbf{Exercise 4.1.}$ An $R-$module $M$ is said to be $\textit{cyclic}$ if it is generated by a singleton subset.  Let $M=Rx$ be a cyclic $R-$module.  Prove that the $R-$module $M$ and $R/\textit{Ann}_R(x)$ are $R-$isomorphic.
[Recall that $\textit{Ann}_R(x)=\{\lambda; \lambda x=0\}.$]  Dededuce that if $R$ is a principal ideal domain (i.e., a commutative integral domain in which every ideal is generated by a single subset) and if $x$ is such that $\textit{Ann}_R(x)=p^k R$ for some $p\in R$ then the only submodules of $M$ are those in the chain
$$0=p^k M\subset p^{k-1}M\subset\ldots\subset pM\subset p^0 M=M.$$

[Hint.  Use the correspondence theorem.]

Also here is the screenshot of the exercise:

[image]

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

In Exercise 4.1 above, before I can use the correspondence theorem, I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to show that the only submodules are the ones in the chain $0=p^k M\subset p^{k-1}M\subset\ldots\subset pM\subset p^0 M=M.$  Is the reason for it being that $(p^k)\subset (p)\subset M=Rx,$ and $(p^k)\subset (p).$ Since $R$ is a principal ideal domain and $R=Rx,$ Can I say there exists a $p \in R$ such that $R=(p)$ and since $\text{Ann}_R(x)=p^kR,$ then $p^kR=R$

Thank you in advance

Comment: What text is this from?

Comment: @morrowmh Module Theory An approach to Linear Algebra by T.S.Blyth

Comment: @morrowmh my main issue is not that I don't know how to use the correspondence theorem for modules.  it is that if $R$ is a principal ideal domain and $R=Rx=M$ and I can let $(p)=R,$ then becuase $M\cong R/\text{Ann}_R(x),$ then can I say that the only submodules of $M$ are the ones in the ascending chain?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a principal ideal domain and let $M$ be an $R$-module.
Assume that there exists $x \in M$ such that $M=Rx$ and $\text{Ann}_R(x) = p^kR$.

Consider a submodule of $M$.
Since $M \cong R/\text{Ann}_R(x)$, we can say that this submodule is the image of some submodule of $R/\text{Ann}_R(x)$ under the isomorphism $R/\text{Ann}_R(x) \to M$.

By the correspondence theorem, every submodule of $R/\text{Ann}_R(x)$ is of the form $I/\text{Ann}_R(x)$, where $I$ is an ideal of $R$ containing $\text{Ann}_R(x)$.

Since $\text{Ann}_R(x) = p^kR$ and $R$ is a principal ideal domain, the ideals of $R$ containing $\text{Ann}_R(x)$ are of the form $p^lR$, where $l \in \{0,\dots,k\}$. (Check this!)

Finally, prove that the image of $p^lR/\text{Ann}_R(x)$ under the isomorphism $R/\text{Ann}_R(x) \to M$ is $p^lM$.

Comment: Can I just check with you where you say "Since $\text{Ann}_R(x) = p^kR$ and $R$ is a principal ideal domain, the ideals of $R$ containing $\text{Ann}_R(x)$ are of the form $p^lR$."   If $R$ is a PID, then $\text{Ann}_R(x) = p^kR\subset R=Rx=M$ and hence it is also a PID.  Also since Since $R$ is a cyclic module, that would also make $\text{Ann}_R(x) = p^kR$ cyclic submodule, and hence any proper ideals which are also submodules are of the form $p^IR.$  Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: @Seth That is not correct. $R$ is not equal to $Rx$, instead, $R/p^k R \cong Rx$.